# how to get current month and year of Kendo calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, kendo-ui

Is there any way get current month of calendar? when I navigate through navigation options in calendar, I wanted to display previous, present and next month and year.

Comment: Kendo datepicker have the default options of previous and next month.
Can you show your code.?

Comment: var calendar = $("#calendar").data("kendoCalendar");
        // bind to the change event
        calendar.bind("navigate", function () {
// Here I wanted to display month and year
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your calendar as follows you will get a trace in the console every time you change month displaying the previous, current and next month.

```
var cal = $("#cal").kendoCalendar({
    navigate: function (e) {
        var cur = new Date(this._current);
        var prev = new Date(cur);
        prev.setMonth(cur.getMonth() - 1);
        var next = new Date(cur);
        next.setMonth(cur.getMonth() + 1);
        console.log("-----------");
        console.log("prev", prev);
        console.log("cur ", cur);
        console.log("next", next);
    }
}).data("kendoCalendar");
```

What I do is get from `_current` the pre-selected date on current displayed month and then increment or decrement by one the month number.

Running example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/W9VFB/1/

Comment: Remember that in JavaScript, months -when used as a number- are 0-base (January = 0) while the day of the month are 1-base. I.e.: January 1st, 1970 is 1970 0 1 (year month day). **But** this is not true when you convert it to string that they show the _correct_ value

Answer (score 0):

You can define depth to year, so the calender will show months and years. I hope this will help you.

```
 $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
    depth: "year"
     });
```

Comment: No, I wanted to display month and year (something like July 2013, Aug 2013, June 2013) when we navigate to front or back.

Comment: in the calender or in the navigation?

Comment: When I navigate, I should get an alert with these details